# SQL errors when using INTERSECT operator

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, intersect

I'm trying to find results that are found by both a category-based search and a keyword search. But in phpMyAdmin, this code is bringing up errors:

```
SELECT ID, post_title 
FROM wp_5_posts AS p
LEFT JOIN wp_5_term_relationships AS r ON p.ID = r.object_id
WHERE r.term_taxonomy_id
IN (41, 9 )
AND p.post_type = 'attachment'
GROUP BY p.ID
HAVING COUNT(*)>1

INTERSECT

SELECT ID, post_title
FROM wp_5_posts
WHERE post_title
LIKE '%process%'
AND post_type='attachment'
```

I am receiving this error:

*"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTERSECTION SELECT ID, post_title FROM wp_5_posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%powd' at line 11"*

Can someone explain to me what the problem is

Comment: `INTERSECT` in `mysql` is not available.

Comment: I think INTERSECT  in MySQL is not a function, you can use using UNION ALL and GROUP BY

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (not tested), but concept should be like this

```
SELECT ID, post_title  from (
  (
    SELECT ID, post_title 
    FROM wp_5_posts AS p
    LEFT JOIN wp_5_term_relationships AS r ON p.ID = r.object_id
    WHERE r.term_taxonomy_id IN (41, 9 ) AND p.post_type = 'attachment'
  )
  UNION ALL
  (
    SELECT ID, post_title
    FROM wp_5_posts
    WHERE post_title LIKE '%process%' AND post_type='attachment'
  )
) AS t1 GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(*)>1;
```